# admin login issues on Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

[image: screen shot showing login screen]

The image is my admin login screen. I have not made any changes in months but now can't log in and the image shows the login screen. I have tried to cleared cache and sessions etc but no change. I have tried on all browsers. I have tried clearing browser cache. I have tried to restore from a few days earlier but same issue. Can anyone give me any other options to try. I have searched but nothing seems similar to this issue.

Comment: Forget to mention that the frontend seems to be operational as normal.

Comment: Log File shows this ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Model_Store::setWebsite() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Model_Website, null given, called in

Comment: it seems that the admin login page is not loading fully

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me via phpmyadmin:

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store`SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;